# Time stamping (anonymous access)

Tags: time, anonymous

Boys and girls Greetings!
I need your help in TSA (time stamping authority).
The problem is that the company which is expected to work according to RFC 3161 does not work perfectly after that. The problem with anonymous access because the access control and user authentication does not allow anonymous access, as is required by the RFC 3161. How could be it resolved that the access would be anonymous? Thanks

Comment: Unclear what you are asking? Are you having a problem with a particular service provider?

Comment: Hello.Yes I have a problem with Poštarca (this is one of provider in Slovenia). My ask is: it is posible to do a authentication anonymous?

Comment: You have to ask them. If they charge for their service, probably not.

Comment: Ok I have another question. How covnert a XML to RFC 3161? Any idea?